# Accepting credit card information/processing

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery

I am going to be embarking on a new project and was wondering what I should do about accepting credit card information, charging, etc.. I know I can use PayPal but I would rather do something quick and easy without having to be charged to make those transactions and stuff across accounts.

Let me explain a little more, this new project I am going to have to make it so a user can come, enter credit card information and add that money to a bank account that will be the company's customer side bank account so when they use to go pay something the money they put in is in the account and so it gets sent to whatever was payed for, plus other differences.

So question, what should I do about te credit car part and what's the best way.  I know the whole group behind making sure ur customers card information is safe is a big hassle.  So let me know what you think!

David

Comment: got any code to share?

Comment: If you don't want a turnkey solution like Paypal, you need to sign up with a *credit card gateway service* (or the CC companies themselves, good luck with that). That's substantially more involved than Paypal, not "quick and easy". Also, if you're going to store CC information, you're obliged to adhere to certain security standards (google them, can't think of the name before my coffee), which is *infinitely more involved*.

Comment: No I'm just asking what you guys thought?

Comment: Deceze what do you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Word for word, what you are asking for is not possible. Credit cards are not bank transfers -- a completed charge is not immediately deposited in a bank account. There is a delay, typically of one or more weeks, before a payment is received by the merchant.

If you want to process credit cards without using PayPal, you should probably take a look at [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). Read their terms carefully before starting a project; it's not entirely clear what you're planning to do, but the service you're describing may run afoul of the [Restricted Use](https://stripe.com/us/terms#restricted-use) section of their ToS. (The same issues will arise with almost any other credit card processor as well; Stripe's terms are not unusual.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for may sound simple, but there's a huge compliance risk here. Read up on [PCI Compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) to get a grasp for how much red tape you've got to deal with.

It'll help you get a better idea of what sorts of controls you have to put in place to manage this process, thereby answering (at least part) of your question.